Django CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS and http/2
I suspect websites that use http/2 protocol are not sending the Host header in the requests, eg going to /admin/

This leads to Django complains about Origin checking failed - does not match any trusted origins) even though posting to the exact same domain.
This error won't come up with websites that using http/1 protocol on Django 4.2
Apart from adding the actual domain to CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS, is there anything else I can do?
